# Java regex won't return capture groups

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I want to use a regular expression parse a date string in the format "MM/DD/YYYY".  I tried making capture groups with parentheses, but it doesn't seem to work.  It only returns the entire matched string -- not the "MM", "DD", and "YYYY" components.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})");
    Matcher m1=p1.matcher("04/30/1999");

    // Throws IllegalStateException: "No match found":
    //System.out.println("Group 0: "+m1.group(0));

    // Runs only once and prints "Found: 04/30/1999".
    while (m1.find()){
        System.out.println("Found: "+m1.group());
    }
    // Wanted 3 lines: "Found: 04", "Found: 30", "Found: 1999"
}
```

The "`group`" function that takes an argument (`m1.group(x)`) doesn't seem to work at all, as it returns an exception no matter what index I give it.  Looping over the `find()`'s only returns the single whole match "04/30/1999".  The parentheses in the regular expression seem to be completely useless!

This was pretty easy to do in Perl:

```
my $date = "04/30/1999";
my ($month,$day,$year) = $date =~ m/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/;
print "Month: ",$month,", day: ",$day,", year: ",$year;
# Prints:
#     Month: 04, day: 30, year: 1999
```

What am I missing?  Are Java regular expressions unable to parse out capture groups like in Perl?

Answer (score 6):

Call `m1.find()` first, then use `m1.group(N)`

`matcher.group()` or `matcher.group(0)` return the whole matched text.
`matcher.group(1)` returns the text matched by the first group.
`matcher.group(2)` returns the text matched by the second group.
...

**Code**

```
Pattern p1=Pattern.compile("(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4})");
Matcher m1=p1.matcher("04/30/1999");

if (m1.find()){ //you can use a while loop to get all match results
    System.out.println("Month: "+m1.group(1)+" Day: "+m1.group(2)+" Year: "+m1.group(3));
}
```

**Result**

```
Month: 04 Day: 30 Year: 1999
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/OAtIzh)